# Why does Firefox have a different Request Header than IE for the same Request?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, firefox, httprequest, request-headers

I do not understand why the same web page with the same request creates different Request Headers for Firefox and Internet Explorer.

For example IE has some Authorization info whereas FF seems to me that it is missing that.

What is the main reason that results different Request Headers for different browser?
(I assume this will give me a clue why my WCF Service call fails for FF but works in IE)

***For Firefox***

```
OPTIONS http://.....
Host: foo.bar.uk
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: null
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

***For Internet-Explorer***

```
POST  http://.....
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Host: foo.bar.uk
Content-Length: 19...
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Authorization: Basic xyxzyxyxzyxyzyxz

{"Foo":"bar","KungFoo":"Judo",...}
```

Comment: You're comparing totally different requests. Please explain your real problem. Read the RFC to learn about each header.

Comment: Then why the requests are different where I exactly use the same HTML ? :(

Comment: I don't know, what does html have to do with that?

Comment: CodeCaster: the HTML (+JS) drives the browser, and the browser then makes the next request. pencilCake: I already answered your question; see below.

Comment: @JulianReschke I know, I was asking because OP does not show any code that is making HTTP requests, just the requests themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Firefox version supports CORS (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), whereas your IE version does not.

Comment: I assume because the server you are POSTing to does not correctly reply to the CORS preflight request. See http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-request.

Comment: But it seems it can do that for IE 9 for some reason. Thanks for the opinion Julian

Comment: IE9 implements "XDR" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which might cause it to behave differently.

At the end of the day, you will need to provide more information. It appears that you try to do a cross-domain POST from XHR, right?

Comment: Correct! I try to post a request to WCF service that sits in a different domain. IE9 does this without any problem when I set jQuery.support.CORS = True; but it fails on IE8 and FF.

Comment: At  the first glance, that it sounds to me like IE9 implements XDR implicitly but for previous versions I might need to implement it in my code explicitly.